# Continuous Assertion failed on Windonws 2008 R2 check build using WinDBG

Tags: debugging, kernel, windbg

I am debugging a Windows 2008 Enterprise check build 6002 and there is an assertion that keeps showing again and again. The error does not interest me as it is not related to our developed driver and I would like to ignore it, but not once, repeatedly.

```
*** Assertion failed: RtlEqualUnicodeString( &foundNode->NameInfo.Name, &nameCacheNode->NameInfo.Name, (FlagOn( nameCacheNode->TreeLink.Flags, NNFL_CASE_SENSITIVE ) ? FALSE : TRUE ))
***   Source File: d:\longhorn\base\fs\filtermgr\filter\namecachesup.c, line 2545
```

Any ideas how can I get rid of this assertion failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable the event in windbg using the option 'Debug' -> 'Event Filters'

You'll want to set it disabled, and you can access the help menu from this screen that will give you more details.